# What is the proper request format for adding a document to an existing DocuSign envelope?

Tags: docusignapi

To add a document to an existing draft DocuSign envelope, it seems as though one makes a multipart PUT call to /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents (see [this page](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Add%20Documents%20to%20a%20Draft%20Envelope.htm?TocPath=REST%20API%20References%7C_____40)).

In the example on the site, I see one form part that defines the data that will be sent (i.e. document names and IDs), and remaining parts have the documents themselves.

The example is only provided in JSON format, whereas I am using XML. I suspect that I am missing something when I infer the format due to JSON being less verbose.

When I make my request, I get a response stating that something is wrong, but doesn't give me quite enough information to rectify it:

```
<errorDetails xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><errorCode>INVALID_MULTI_PART_REQUEST</errorCode><message>An error was found while parsing the multipart request. The XML request does not match the expected format. </message></errorDetails>
```

Here is the body of the request I am making (with the document truncated)

```
--mq1mFxUoPiKbAACz7JGKBlpTp1SsHEu5O
Content-Disposition: form-data
Content-Type: application/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><documents xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi"><document><name>fw4.pdf</name><documentId>2</documentId></document></documents>
--mq1mFxUoPiKbAACz7JGKBlpTp1SsHEu5O
Content-Disposition: file; filename="fw4.pdf"; documentId=2
Content-Type: application/pdf

%PDF-1.7
(etc.)
%%EOF

--mq1mFxUoPiKbAACz7JGKBlpTp1SsHEu5O--
```

I believe what I need is the proper format of the XML portion of the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you still need to have the `<envelopeDefinition></envelopeDefinition>` tabs in your XML body.  Try this:

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
    <documents>
        <document>
        <name>fw4.pdf</name>
        <documentId>2</documentId>
        </document>
    </documents>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

Comment: Worked for me. I added the following to my EnvelopeDefinition JAXB entity: `@XmlElementWrapper(name = "documents") @XmlElement(name = "document") private List<DocumentRequest> documents;`